# Read lines looping over array which contains filenames in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, shell, for-loop

In bash, I would like to loop over a previously defined array, which contains filenames. In turn, each file of the array must be readed and processed dynamically (`while read line...`).

This is an example of what the files of the array contains:

```
_VALUE1_,_VALUE1_,1,Name 1
_VALUE2_,_VALUE2_,1,Name 2
_VALUE3_,_VALUE3_,1,Name 3
_VALUE4_,_VALUE4_,1,Name 4
_VALUE5_,_VALUE5_,1,Name 5
```

This is what I've tested with no luck.

```
#!/bin/bash

. functions.sh

GEN_ARQ_ARRAY=("./cfg_file.txt" "./euro_file.txt" "./zl_file.txt")
WB_ARQ_ARRAY=("./rn_cfg_wb_file.txt" "./rn_eur_wb_file.txt" "./rn_zl_wb_file.txt")
BN_ARQ_ARRAY=("./rn_cfg_bn_file.txt" "./rn_eur_bn_file.txt" "./rn_zl_bn_file.txt")
AM_ARQ_ARRAY=("./rn_cfg_am_file.txt" "./rn_eur_am_file.txt" "./rn_zl_am_file.txt")

STATUS_BOOL=true

for i in "${!GEN_ARQ_ARRAY[@]}"; do

    while IFS=$'\r' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]];do
        STACK_NAME=${line%%,*} # Gets the first substring of a string divided by ','

        STACK_STATUS=$(curl -su "${USERNAME}":"${PASSWORD}" -X GET http://"${SERVER_NAME}":9100/api/stacks/"${STACK_NAME}"/state | ./jq-linux64 -cr '.result.value')

        if [[ $(echo "$STACK_STATUS" | tr -d '\r') == "$STATUS_BOOL" ]]; then
            echo "${line}" >> "${GEN_ARQ_ARRAY[i]}"
            case ${line} in
                *"ARQBS"*|*"ARCBS"*|*"ARQWB"*|*"ARCWB"*) echo "${line}" >> "${WB_ARQ_ARRAY[$i]}";;
                *"ARQOF"*|*"ARCOF"*|*"ARQBN"*|*"ARCBN"*) echo "${line}" >> "${BN_ARQ_ARRAY[$i]}";;
                *"ARQAM"*|*"ARCAM"*) echo "${line}" >> "${AM_ARQ_ARRAY[$i]}";;
                *) echo "$(logWarn) No matches -- ${STACK_NAME}" | tee -a "$LOGFILE";;
            esac
        else
            echo "$(logInfo) ${STACK_NAME} is not running" | tee -a "$LOGFILE"
        fi
    done < "${GEN_ARQ_ARRAY[i]}"
done
```

Problem here is that the `for` loop starts, detects array content, gets the first value of the array, enter into `while`, and it constantly loops in the first position of the array even with the end of the file is reached. I can't find the way to exit the `while` loop and continue with the next array position.

I'm pretty sure there is a better way to implement this.

Hearing your ideas!

Edit:

Solved by replacing the line `echo "${line}" >> "${GEN_ARQ_ARRAY[i]}"`, which was in-loop filling up the file.

Comment: Why do you loop over the keys of the `GEN_ARQ_ARRAY` (that is, 0, 1 and 2)? And inside this outermost loop you redirect `"${GEN_ARQ_ARRAY[@]}"`, that is, the 3 file names in your `GEN_ARQ_ARRAY` to the input of the `while` loop. This cannot work, you can't redirect more than one file at a time.

Comment: @markp-fuso my mistake changing some variables to copy here. My code is with `[i]` instead of `[@]` so thanks for pointing it out. Unfortunately it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I suppose you are referring to the same thing as *markp-fuso*, right?

Comment: @smt Yes (I simply did not see their comment before I wrote mine). You should definitely fix your question.

Comment: Silly mistake! The problem was here `echo "${line}" >> "${GEN_ARQ_ARRAY[i]}"`. That's the reason of the infinite loop. Removed that line solved the issue. Thanks both!

Comment: Not relevant to the problem, but the case patterns can be tidied up using extended patterns. Add `shopt -s extglob` and then the first patten can be `*@(ARQBS|ARCBS|ARQWB|ARCWB)*)`. See [3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) in the manual

Comment: @glennjackman will check it now, thank you for the suggest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by replacing the line `echo "${line}" >> "${GEN_ARQ_ARRAY[i]}"`, which was in-loop filling up the file. Once I did, the code worked flawlessly.